# How to compare git branches in VS code with editing option?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-diff

Is there an option in VS code/GitLens to compare the current branch with other branch while allowing to edit the current branch in the comparison view (like when viewing unstaged changes in source control)?

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to compare your local checkout with another branch? If so, this can be done with the GitLens extension.  Once installed, press <kbd>F1</kbd>, search for "**GitLens: Compare Working Tree with ...**".  This will give you a list of branches to compare with.  After selecting a branch, the comparisons can be seen by selecting a file in the **SEARCH & COMPARE** area of the SOURCE CONTROL window.  You can then see the differences and edit the current file.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend you to use:
[Git History](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.githistory)

It supports all features that you mentioned.